# Is there a way to activate Adsense based upon location?

Tags: google-adsense, traffic

I have a cloth store that only works in my country, but It receives some traffic from other countries as well, those other countries are not useful at all, so I was thinking if there is a way to activate `Adsense` based upon location in order to take advantage of those visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is through [Google DFP](https://www.google.com/dfp/).

Setup an account there and create a house ad where you add your Adsense code. Then you can choose the geotargeting you want for the ads.

Comment: I have submitted my application It's being reviewed, thanks a lot, I will see tomorrow if it works.